# Classicthesis bibliography formatting

Tags: bibliographies, margins, classicthesis

I am using classicthesis to write my PhD thesis.

I need a way to customize the margins of the bibliography (I'm using biblatex) and avoid a huge number of just slightly overfull hboxes (e.g. just quotation marks or dashes protruding).

I really don't want to change the page size of the whole document or load and try hacking around with the geometry package, which overrides all default settings of the template.

Any suggestions on how to change margins only locally?

Comment: Check how this is done in Titlepage.tex: `\begin{addmargin}[..]{..}    \end{addmargin}`

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I'm a bit confused though, because I had already tried \begin{addmargin*} since in the docs it says that's what you're supposed to use in two-page format, but it doesn't compile and instead throws a "You can't use `\unskip' in vertical mode." error. Do you know what this is about?